# Getting Selected Item with composite collection in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, binding, compositecollection

I am trying to set itemsSource of a listbox to a compositecollection.

```
<ListBox x:Name="moduleMenu" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSourceViewDetail}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                            <CompositeCollection>
                                <ListBoxItem DataContext="{Binding SourceModule.Settings}" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding SourceModule.ExtraViews}" />
                            </CompositeCollection>
                        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
                    </ListBox>
```

However the binding with selectedItem is not working. How can I get the selected item in viewmodel when an item gets selected?

Comment: what is the type of SelectedSourceViewDetail?

Comment: yes, i got that. setting the type to object returned a listboxitem, but it is not what i wanted. I want the datacontext of the selected item. the type of datacontext of the listboxitem and the items in collectioncontainer are the same.

Comment: then i would suggest you to use converter which returns CompositeCollection and bind that collection to ItemsSource. You are adding Listboxitem  and collectioncontatiner in the itemsSource. CompositeCollection will be collection of Settings and ExtraViews

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the ItemsSource as you did in xaml. I would suggest you to use converter which returns CompositeCollection and bind that collection to ItemsSource. CompositeCollection will be collection of Settings and ExtraViews

Your binding will look like `ItemsSource = "{Binding SourceModel, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"`. In Convert method of converter create composite collection from sourcemodel.Settings and sourcemodel.ExtraViews and return.

Thanks